# nightmare.js - $ not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, nightmare

I want to use `jquery` in my web scraping with `nightmare.js`. Based on [this tutorial](https://davidburgos.blog/jquery-not-defined-nightmarejs/), I can just `inject` the `jquery` and copy the file to the same root folder. But somehow I still get error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Below is my code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');

new Nightmare()
  .goto('http://google.com')
  .inject('js', 'jquery.min.js')
  .wait()
  .run(function(err, nightmare) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    };

    var items = [];

    $('.someclass').each(function(){//<-- error - $ not defined
        item = {};
        item.value = $(this).val();
        items.push(item);
    });
    console.log(items);
    });
```

Comment: `nightmare.js` is headless and without html, how can I include `jquery.js` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to interact with the page and its variables, you'll need to use [`.evaluate(fn)`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/tree/2.10.0#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2):

> Invokes `fn` ***on the page*** with `arg1, arg2,...`.

`.evaluate()` changes the context of the `fn` to that of the page, so that it can be execute as though it's client-side code, with access to the `window`, `document`, `$`, and any other globals.

Also, since you've mentioned using version 2.10, the `.run()` function from 1.x versions has been replaced by [`Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you'll want to use `.then()` and `.catch()` to handle successes and errors, respectively.

For your snippet:

```
new Nightmare()
  .goto('http://google.com')
  .inject('js', 'jquery.min.js')
  .wait()
  .evaluate(function() {
    var items = [];

    $('.someclass').each(function(){
        item = {};
        item.value = $(this).val();
        items.push(item);
    });

    console.log(items);
  })
  .then(function () {
    console.log('Done');
  });
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  });
```

The project's readme includes [a few examples of this method chain](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/tree/2.10.0#examples).

Comment: `npm list` show my version is `nightmare@2.10.0`. I believe I am not sure how `evaluate()` works. The example is not very descriptive.

Comment: @sooon I've updated my answer to focus on v2.10, then.